# Preventing checkbox from being deselected when click trigger is on parent element

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Kind of a funny problem here.

I want to check the checkbox when the parent div is checked, but it is DESELECTING the checkbox when the CHECKBOX is clicked on ;)

It works fine when the name is clicked on. How do i solve this?

```
//layout
<div class="parent">
   <input type="checkbox"/> <a>Name</a>
</div>

//check the box when parent div is clicked
$(".parent").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   checkbox=$(this).find("input:checkbox");
   checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div class="parent">
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"/> <a>Name</a>
</div>

$(".parent").click(function(event){
    $(".check:not(:checked)").attr('checked','checked');
});
$(".check").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/waPRu/)

Comment: this doesn't work (anymore?), use `event.preventDefault();` instead of `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I suspect you can prevent the parent's action from running by preventing the event from bubbling like so:

```
$(".parent input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Alternatively, you could just put your click handler on the `<a>Name</a>` element or use a `<label>` element without adding any JS (this is exactly what `<label>` is for).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
event.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

to your event handler.

So, your code looks like:

```
//layout
<div class="parent">
   <input type="checkbox"/> <a>Name</a>
</div>

//check the box when parent div is clicked
$(".parent").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();

   checkbox=$(this).find("input:checkbox");
   checkbox.attr("checked","checked");

   return false;
});
```

...

Documentation for event.stopPropagation():
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/